# how to display dialog box on click of items in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, dialog

I am trying to display a dialog box when a particular item is clicked, but I can only see a little box in place of the layout I have set. here is the onbindview holder.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListEventAdapter.ListEventViewHolder holder, int position) {
        EventResponse event = eventList.get(position);
```

view to be clicked

```
        holder.home_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showAlertDialog(view);

            }
        });
```

```
   private void showAlertDialog(View view) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
     
        home_t = dialog.findViewById(R.id.home_t);

        place_btn = (CircularProgressButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.place_bet_btn);
        close = dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);

        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        place_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();


    }
```

Comment: Please kindly paste your Dialog's XML also.

Answer (score 0):

on **R.layout.alert_dialog** just use **match_parent** in **layout_width**